# How to install Ubuntu 14.04 alongside the same existing OS in laptop?

Tags: system-installation, dual-boot

I already have Ubuntu 14.04 installed on my laptop. But it's not working properly. I've a related thread [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/637109/the-package-libfdk-aac0-needs-to-be-reinstalled-but-i-cant-find-an-archive-for?noredirect=1#comment910020_637109). I urgently require an audio/video cutter like ffmpeg, avconv etc. to be installed which isn't happening in the current system. So, the need to install a fresh one where I will install the cutter.

I want to install again the same OS but where! For that please look at my existing hard disk in my laptop.

[image: partitions]

See, I've Windows on sda2 & sda3. But it's not working any more & so I'm interested to delete sda2 & install the new Ubuntu 14.04 there. But I need 3 partitions for the new installation. If I delete sda2, then can I install Ubuntu 14.04 by creating 3 partitions? I'm doubtful as already there is 1 extended & 3 primary. So, if I delete one primary (sda2), then how to get the 3 partitions as logical partitions can't be made inside primary!!

Another method: Just now something striked my mind. Shall I create only root (or boot even required) partition on sda2 & use the other partitions  (/home etc) from the existing ones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why would you need 3 partitions? You only need one. Either sda2 or sda3 are big enough for a normal installation.

The new installation normally will overwrite your boot sector, if you don't want that make sure to deselect that option. In that case you will have to boot
in the old 14.04 and run update-grub for it to find the new 14.04 and add it to the grub menu.

Comment: Nice to see your answer as I need a soulution urgently for an audio cutter to be installed as metioned in my Q. 1) 3 partitions for /, /boot, /home at least! you interpreted differently the 3 partitions I mentioned about. 2) I feel it's O.K. to overwrite the existing boot sector. While installation, I will install the boot loader in sda & that should have no problem as while booting the GRUB bootloader menu will show the previous Ubuntu also along with the new one to choose from. Am I right please?

Comment: @Ravi You don't need 3 partitions. I have been running Ubuntu for over 10 years with a single one, or one plus swap (which you don't seem to have) or with two if I shared /home between tow revisions. You are not right. And of course you can install the boot sector and boot the old one from the new installation.

Comment: O.K., there are many ways of doing. So, I go the way as you mentioned in your answer. So, I delete sda2 & then what partition do I need to specify it as while installing (is it " / " ? ). As I don't have another partition for swap, then isn't it required to specify the partition of swap while installing? Now, the 2nd point:  as mentioned in your answer, I will deselect that option of boot sector. Now running update-grub & adding to grub menu, what's the complete method? If it's simple it would be great & I will proceed immediately.

Comment: @Ravi you only need the `/` partition. Swap can be done in a file, not sure how to specify that in 14.04. You can  add swap afterwards. update-grub scans (normally) all the partitions and sees that the new 14.04 has been installed. It should add it to its menu. At least that way it is really hard to further break your old 14.04. Make sure to select the right partition to delete and install the 2nd 14.04!

Comment: Also please confirm that deleting sda2 won't have any problem in loading the current Ubuntu 14.04! Ubuntu 14.04 is the latest one I'd installed & GRUB 2 bootloader comes up while booting my laptop. So deleting sda2 won't interfere anywhere!

Comment: I am not sure what is on /dev/sda2, but It sure doesn't look like it is being used by Ubuntu from what I can see (but I have not seen the /etc/fstab nor the grub.cfg). I recommend you make a backup of your drive first so you can restore in case of disaster. And at least make a backup of valuable data.

Comment: I wnat to proceed ahead without further ado but please clarify the swap point. You told I can add afterwards, is it simple to do & how to do it? I don't want that I install, then do update-grub but still swap issue comes!

Comment: You can put swap either on its own partition, or in a dedicated file. Yes it is simple. Unless you are really tight on memory you should be able to start without swap, as you have done until now. I would probably delete `sda8` and make `/tmp` for the old 14.04 a tmpfs based partition, and reuse that for swap (depending on the size of your RAM). Make sure you have a backup of your valuable data on the machine, changing partitions etc, can always lead to a problem.

Comment: I'd always created a seperate swap earlier. when you say " You can put swap either on its own partition " , do you mean that the single partition (sda2) that I will be using for the new OS, there only swap can be put. But what's the method for that? I've only 1 GB RAM, so I'm tight on memory. You missed one Q I asked in previous comment as while installation the partition needs to be assigned as root (/)? So, no seperate "/boot" then!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24944/discussion-between-anthon-and-ravi).

Comment: I will install boot loader on the same partition (sda2) as that of Ubuntu?

Comment: No, you should put it on the /dev/sda not on a partition, otherwise what is in the bootsector of /dev/sda is unlikely to find it.

Comment: Can u come on chat plz

Comment: If I install on /dev/sda, that is what I asked in my 1st comment to your answer, that shouldn't be any problem. And then after installation is complete, when I boot the laptop that's what I asked that my previous installation  will be there in the bootloader menu? You replied 'no'. Is it no or yes?